# Representation theory of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, real-numbers

I am just learning a bit about representation theory (a representation being a homomorphism $\rho: G \to GL(V)$ for some complex vector space $V$) and I am trying to understand some examples. I get the representations of the finite cyclic groups and I think I get the representations of the integers. I am wondering about the representations of a group like $\mathbb{R}$ under addition. I know this group is Abelian, and so all the irreducible representations would be $1$-dimensional. If this is too hard I would be happy with a reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case of an infinite topological group, you probably want to consider only continuous characters. In the compact case, the Peter-Weyl theorem holds, and the situation is similar to the finite case. If you consider arbitrary representations of $\mathbb{R}$, then you can construct some uninteresting and pathological ones from a Hamel basis. In the abelian case, the characters are more or less determined by Pontryagin duality, assuming local compactness. For the particular case of $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that the continuous characters on $\mathbb{R}$ are all of the form $\chi(t) = e^{2\pi i \xi t}$ for some real $\xi$, with the correspondence induced by the Fourier transform.

Comment: Ok, and to clarify, you get one for each real number $\xi$?

Comment: Right. If you unravel Pontryagin duality, the content is that the map $\xi \to (t \to e^{2\pi i \xi t})$ is an isomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{R}, S^1)$, where the latter is the space of _continuous_ maps $\mathbb{R} \to S^1$.

Comment: A minor point, but if you're looking for all representations you should not restrict to ones with absolute value $1$, so adding in the magnitude you get $\chi(t)=e^{zt}$ for any complex number $z$.

Answer (score 7):

For fun, let's drop the assumption of continuity. $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, and so (assuming choice) it has a basis, and hence is an infinite direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$. The representation theory of $\mathbb{Q}$ is surprisingly complicated: explicitly, the $1$-dimensional representations are given by picking nonzero complex numbers $z_n \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ such that

$$z_{nm}^m = z_n$$

for all $i, j$, and then taking

$$\mathbb{Q} \ni \frac{p}{q} \mapsto z_q^p \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}.$$

The obvious examples are given by taking $z_n = \exp \frac{2 \pi i \xi}{n}$ for some $\xi \in \mathbb{C}$ but other examples are possible.

Moreover, the representation theory of $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't semisimple; for example,

$$\mathbb{Q} \ni r \mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & r \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$$

is a $2$-dimensional representation which is indecomposable but not irreducible. I don't know off the top of my head how to classify these. And then $\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$ on top of that...

Comment: Ah, ok, so you are saying that from these representations of $\mathbb{Q}$ one can find all the representations of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @John: no, I'm saying it's at least as hard to classify the representations of $\mathbb{R}$ as the representations of $\mathbb{Q}$, but it could be even harder. Already it's not clear how to classify the representations of $G \times H$ starting from the representations of $G$ and the representations of $H$ unless e.g. $G, H$ are both compact. And $\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite direct sum.

Comment: So far what we have is a description of the $1$-dimensional representations of $\mathbb{R}$: if $I$ is a set indexing a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, then $1$-dimensional representations are given by nonzero complex numbers $z_{n, i}, i \in I$ such that $z_{nm, i}^m = z_{n, i}$.

Answer (score 5):

For topological groups like $\mathbb{R}$, the useful objects to study are the continuous representations (or the continuous characters in the case of an abelian group).

It turns out that all continuous characters of $\mathbb{R}$ have the form $\chi(x)=e^{2\pi i\xi x}$ for some $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$. This is generally proved in books that cover Fourier analysis. See for instance Chapter 8 of Folland's *Real Analysis*.

Comment: (of course, one could also consider it as an algebraic group and get even fewer representations).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Would you elaborate on this?

Comment: Hmm... what about the map: $x \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.
This is an indecomposable representation with character $\chi(x)=2$

Answer (score 1):

By the way, though it is true that all irreducibles are 1-dimensional, not all continuous representations split into characters. For example,
$$t \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & t\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$ is indecomposable but not irreducible.