# Representations of $F^{\times}$

Tags: field-theory, representation-theory

I have a sort of follow-up question to [Representation theory of $\mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922960/representation-theory-of-mathbbr)

If we have a finite field $F$, then $F^{\times}$ is a cyclic group. And so I believe that I understand how the representations (homomorphisms $G \to GL(V)$) work out.

My question is how this works when $F$ is an infinite field?

I get from the other answer, that considering representations of fields (considered as groups) is a bit tricky, but I am wondering what can be said when the one takes the units.

If this is too complicated or too broad, then I would welcome a reference.

For example, what is the representation theory of $\mathbb{R}^\times$?

Comment: If I have time tomorrow, I can elaborate on my comment from the other question about considering such a group as an algebraic group (which is probably one of the best view points for an arbitrary field). The basic idea is that this group can be given a scheme structure as spec of $F[t,t^{-1}]$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Thank you. I will look forward to that.

Comment: $F^{\times}$ can be a complicated group in general, and the assumption that it's the multiplicative group of a field isn't super helpful other than knowing that it's commutative. $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ is just $\{ \pm 1 \} \times \mathbb{R}$, so it's about as hard to understand as $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I offered a bounty on the question.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I offered a bounty on the question.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Why should $F ^\times$ be commutative simply because $F$ is infinite? What about $F$ being the field of quaternions?

Comment: @Alex: the standard convention in English is that fields are commutative. Noncommutative or skew fields are usually called division rings. I think the convention might be different in French.

Comment: Yes, I meant that the field is commutative.

Comment: In what category?  I have no idea what it would look like if you treat $R^*$ as a discrete group.  Maybe its OK, and I am just a chicken. However it seems to me, that $R^*$ is not even countably generated, and there is a chance to do some elementary set theory.

Comment: However, if you are only interested in continuous finite dimensional representations, this is an exercise in canonical forms.